# Design below scenario in JMETER

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

starting with 5 concurrent users running 5 requests per sec, and then going up to 10 users and after with 10 requests.

Can you help on how to design above scenario in JMeter ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/):

[image]

Also be informed that you will get 5 requests per second with 5 users only if response time is exactly 1 second, shorter response time - higher RPS and vice versa. More information: [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)

So you need to provide **sufficient** amount of users in order to maintain the desired throughput. For this you can connect Throughput Shaping Timer with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/).